# How to update views of viewpager on swipe - android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, updates

I am using view-pager.In that I have three tabs : 1. History , 2. Main , 3. Map .

I have stopwatch into main activity.When I press the start and then after stop at that time value of the stopwatch add into the sqlite DB. And into history activity I am fetching the value of stopwatch from DB and store into the listview. It's working perfect.

But now I want the update the History activity when I swipe from the **Main  > History** so After press the stop button,I got the last value into listview of history activity.

My question is `how can I update the view on swipe the viewpager?`

```
public class SwipeyTabsSampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final String [] TITLES = {
    "HISTORY", 
    "MAIN",
    "MAP"  

};

private SwipeyTabs mTabs;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
//Handler handler=new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipeytab);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mTabs = (SwipeyTabs) findViewById(R.id.swipeytabs);

    SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter adapter = new SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(this,
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mTabs.setAdapter(adapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mTabs);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1); 
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);


}

 private class SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        SwipeyTabsAdapter, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    ViewPager viewpager;



    public SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, ViewPager mViewPager) {
        super(fm);

        this.mContext = context;
        viewpager = mViewPager;

        //viewpager.setAdapter(this);
        viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

         Fragment f = new Fragment();

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            f = History.newInstance(position);

            break;
        case 1:
            f = Main.newInstance(position);
            break;
        case 2:
            f = Map.newInstance(position);

            break;

        }
        return f;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }


     @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) container;
            View view = (View) object;

            pager.removeView(view);
        }



    public TextView getTab(final int position, SwipeyTabs root) {
        TextView view = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.swipey_tab_indicator, root, false);
        view.setText(TITLES[position]);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int positiion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

}
```

Comment: please help me for my problem. If your answer is solve my prob then I sure accept it and give upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one string and add the Getters and setters into your `FragmentActivity` class.

Like...

```
String HistoryFragment;

public String getHistoryFragment() {
    return HistoryFragment;
}


public void setHistoryFragment(String historyFragment) {
    HistoryFragment = historyFragment;
}
```

Then after we can access another fragment from our current fragment by calling `findFragmentByTag(<tag of target fragment>)`.

For the more information check the link [Communication between Fragments in ViewPager](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/communication-between-fragments-in.html).

Comment: hey , can you help me with this thread ..http://stackoverflow.com/q/18097567/1503130

Answer (score 9):

Add ViewPager OnPageChangeListener:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // your code here
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: According to android documentation this way is deprecated use : addOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) and removeOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) instead.

Answer (score 2):

This will affect the changes from one page to another page in view pager.

```
OnPageChangeListener pagechangelistener =new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                Logger.logMessage("Called first");

                pageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                indicator.setCurrentItem(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

                Logger.logMessage("Called second");

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

                Logger.logMessage("Called third");

            }
        };
        myViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pagechangelistener);
```

Use this in your page adapter.

```
@Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried implementing OnPageChanged`? You can capture when the user start swiping.

do `pager.setOnPageChanged(new ....)` and Eclipse will show you the methods you can override.
Then you can override `onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)`

```
onPageScrollStateChanged(int state){
    if (state==OnPageChangeListener.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING){
       // update here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But eclipse don't give me option for the `setOnPageScrolledListener` ,

Comment: can you please edit in my code for the better understand? I am new to android. please...

Comment: what is `state` and `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`?

Comment: Thanks, I got it that you advice me for the override methods.NOw please can You suggested me for how can I update view ? can I pass the Intent? or any other way?

Comment: The quick and easy way is to use a BroadcastReceiver. The best practice is to define interfaces. Check the official tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html