# multiple layout viewpager with one fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**I must clear that I am looking for an example or answer where I can use various differnt layout designs in a viewpager and the data in all the pages would be dynamic and all pages can be interacted by the user.**

**My Use Case and current approach towards the problem :**

So I have got 8 different types of question types and so I have created `layouts` for all of them. Also I the data in the views for these layouts has to be populated via java `Map` that has fetched data from the sqlite DB.

But a test may contain 25 questions with different layouts out of the above 8. And for all these 25 questions I want to use a `Viewpager` and a `Fragment` that will return the required layout based on the passed **question type value** out of my java map.

**My apporach towards this :**

I have created an activity and have inflated it with a viewpager layout :

**R.layout.practice_pager**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/test_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />`

**Activity Edited code **

```
       public class TestActivity extends FragmentData implements FragmentData{

            FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
            private ViewPager mViewPager;  
            private MyFragmentPagerAdapter mMyFragmentPagerAdapter;
            int PAGE_COUNT = 0;
            GrePracticeTestRecord p=new GrePracticeTestRecord();
            private HashMap<Integer, GrePracticeResultRecord> mPracResultMap;

            public static int fragmentToReturn=0;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.practice_pager);

                mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.test_container);  

           //This function is called to fetch the data from sqlite db and fill the map with data
                LoadingTestView();

                PAGE_COUNT=mPracRecordMap.size();
                    initPager();
              }

        //here I initialize the pager and set the adapter to it
        public void initPager()
    {
     p.setQUES(mPracRecordMap.get(1).getQUES());
     p.setEXPL(mPracRecordMap.get(1).getEXPL());    

     fragmentToReturn=Integer.parseInt(mPracRecordMap.get(1).getQTYPE());
     setData(p);

     mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fList);  
     mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);  

     mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

            mMyFragmentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            p.setQUES(mPracRecordMap.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()+1).getQUES());
            p.setEXPL(mPracRecordMap.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()+1).getEXPL());

            setData(p);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
  }

           @Override
        public void setData(GrePracticeTestRecord p) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public GrePracticeTestRecord getData() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return p;
        }
    }
```

**My Adapter Edited code**

```
   public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

         private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        /** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            System.out.println("value of position "+position);
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }


        /** Returns the number of pages */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return MyFragmentPagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }
```

**Interface FragmentData**

```
public interface FragmentData {
    public void setData(GrePracticeTestRecord p);
    public GrePracticeTestRecord getData();
}
```

**TestFragment Edited code**

public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

```
AnswerEnterListener callBack;
FragmentData fD;
Button submitAnswer;
EditText userAnswer;

TextView qText,expl;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          return inflater.inflate(R.layout.qtype1, container, false);
}

public interface AnswerEnterListener
{
    public void onInputAnswer(String ans);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        callBack=(AnswerEnterListener) activity;
        fD=(FragmentData) activity;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    qText=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.question_text);
    expl=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.explanation_text);


    qText.setText(Html.fromHtml(fD.getData().getQUES()));
    expl.setText(Html.fromHtml(fD.getData().getEXPL()));

}
```

}

**Similar to TestFragment , I have not the other fragments too. Each for a layout type.**

**Issues :**

- The first layout is repeated two times at the first time , and also when I swipe back then the position of data is misplaced.
- Is this the right approach, I have been suggested by someone that you should use three fragments and update the left and right fragments with data , but this actually bounced off me. Can anyone share a good example of it or a blog.

Comment: You basically want to implement a quiz app where there could be a maximum of 8 types of questions(8 different question layouts), right? *and the data in all the pages would be dynamic* - how dynamic? do you plan to change it **after** the fragment is created? *and all pages can be interacted by the user.* - what does interacted mean?

Comment: Yes you are right I want to implement a quiz. The dynamic data means the data would come from the sqlite db or map but not hardcoded. Yes once the fragment is created I would like to populate it with the data in my collection . There are edittexts on some pages and buttons on all like submit answer , this way it would be interacted.

Comment: @Luksprog Are you going to suggest something Because I want to edit the above code to what I am doing now.

Comment: Update the question. You complicated the code too much for what you want to do.

Comment: @Luksprog Have a look at my edit, actualy now I have created fragments for each layout and have created a list of fragments that returns the required layout when needed. Is this the right approach for my use case , Also the problem with this approach is that I can't update the data on page swipe in my viewpager

Comment: @prateek, sorry bro for the late response. Is there solve your problem?

Comment: @RahulPatel yes bro , just solved it, anyways thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I must clear that I am looking for an example or answer where I can
>   use various differnt layout designs in a viewpager and the data in all
>   the pages would be dynamic and all pages can be interacted by the
>   user.

This should be quite easy to make but you seem to have complicated this a lot. You need to do something like this:

Get the data from the database with the LoadingTestView(); function.

Initialize the `ViewPager` and set it's adapter. The adapter will return the proper fragment instance in the `getItem()` method, based on whatever criteria you have.

In the fragments, retrieve the data from the activity which should expose the data through some method.

I've made a simple example that you can find [here](https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/master/src/com/luksprog/playground/fragment/TestLikeImplem.java).

Comment: Got it , I actualy was doing mistake by initializing my views inside the `onActivityCreated` inspite of `onCreateView` , but this approach by you has really helped. Thanks for your time and valuable input